# Cross domain error on Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm newbie in Backbone and am not able to get the following working. This is in Backbonejs. I am trying to call a REST API and submit a form.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test App</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <!--  Underscore.JS is the dependency library for Backbone.JS-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Jquery is used for DOM manipulation-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Fieldset helps logically grouping the HTML elements  -->
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Post data to Test</legend>
            <!-- Input Field to Enter the data to be sent to the server
                    Backbone.JS code is written to send POST request to the server
                    on clicking the button -->
            <input type="text" id="upload_link" placeholder="Enter the Link" required />
            <input type="button" id="post_data" value="Send data to the Server" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Get Data From Test</legend>
            <input type="button" id="get_data" value="Get Data From Server">
            <!--Backbone.JS code is written to send GET request to the server on clicking the button -->
        </fieldset>
        <div id="data"></div>
        <!-- Div element where data from the server is placed-->
    </body>
    <!-- Backbone.JS code starts here -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Files = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                urlRoot: 'https://lite.test.com/api/file',
                url: function () {
                    return this.urlRoot;
                }
            });
            $('#post_data').click(function () {
                console.log('Post Clicked');
                post_data_to_the_server();
            });
            function post_data_to_the_server() {
                var file = new Files();
                file.fetch({data: {
                        apiKey: 'X93S2ssnwnue1T2y1ssnwGZMLHRiRGpPsQ',
                        email: 'abc@email.com',
                        fileLink: $('#upload_link').val(),
                        firstName: 'Swapnil',
                        lastName: 'Test',
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                });
                $('#upload_link').val('');
            }
        }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error - Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Can you please help?

I tried using various methods but still not able to solve the error. I think this is because we're posting from localhost to another server. Can you help please?

Comment: you are calling ajax request but calling from different server with json data, so you can solve it with send jsonp data.

Comment: But jsonp converts to GET whereas I want it in POST. Is there a way I can do POST using jsonp or other method?

Comment: @SumitJha - please help.